# Need suggestions for a simple formatting script

Tags: bash

I'm very basic Linux user with no formal computer science training. I'm trying to adapt a basic script that moves some data into a different format.

I have a bunch of files with file name XXX. Each containing few headers and columns. The files with .star extension look like this:

```
data_


loop_
_rlnCoordinateX #1
_rlnCoordinateY #2
_rlnClassNumber #3
_rlnAnglePsi #4
_rlnAutopickFigureOfMerit  #5
1189.5  3921.0  -999    -999.0  -999.0
1552.0  3936.5  -999    -999.0  -999.0
607.0   3874.0  -999    -999.0  -999.0
...
```

I want to convert each file into another file containing the first two entries along with the file name. The file name should be in the first column followed by the x and y (coordinates) entries.

So my script looks like this:

```
echo ' ' > ../picks.star
echo 'data_' >> ../picks.star
echo ' ' >> ../picks.star
echo 'loop_' >> ../picks.star
echo '_rlnMicrographName #1' >> ../picks.star
echo '_rlnCoordinateX #2' >> ../picks.star
echo '_rlnCoordinateY #3' >> ../picks.star
        for file in /data/CRYOSPARC/cryolo/full_data/STAR/*.star; do
                awk -v f="$file" '{if (NF>3) printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n", f, $1, $2}' $file >> ../picks.star; done
```

What I hope to get is this:

```
data_

loop_
_rlnMicrographName #1
_rlnCoordinateX #2
_rlnCoordinateY #3

filename1.star 1189.5  3921.0
filename1.star 1552.0  3936.5
...
...
...
filename2.star 1234.3 1234.5
```

and so on.
I have two problems that I can't wrap my head around. When I run the script I get this:

```
./script.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

And secondly I get an output named picks.star? (don't know why there is a ? mark) and the file appears largely empty:

```
data_

loop_
_rlnMicrographName #1
_rlnCoordinateX #2
_rlnCoordinateY #3
```

My best guess is that the "for file" part is not reading the *.star files correctly.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sounds like you are asking us to tell you about [tag:awk]. Unfortunately, asking for recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off topic for SO.

Comment: Dear @SiKing. Sorry, that is certainly not my intention. My intention was to ask for help to get the script to do what I want it to do.  If that is off topic then I'll delete it and ask somewhere else.

Comment: So what is the problem? Your script seems to produce the desired output.

Comment: Ah fair enough. I did not even discuss the error message or the output. Please see the edited comment. Basically the script does not work as intended and I am not sure why.

Comment: You might want to try adding `set -x` before the first `echo` to see what the script is doing exactly and what variable values `awk` is trying to run, and then troubleshoot from there

Comment: @Omid - You shouldn't have posted a script which only _looks like_ yours, but does not produce the syntax error.

Comment: @Armali What are you suggesting? My goal is to learn a little bash scripting and try to figure out how this script can get fixed. A very similar script was posted by a fellow scientist on a forum for cryosparc (program we use). Rather than pestering them I figured I try to learn why it is not working for me, then post the updated script there. I am not sure what rule I am breaking, but I am happy to be educated.

Comment: @ThatsWhatSheCoded, thanks for the suggestion. Still learning this stuff so I don't know a whole lot. When I try your suggestions I get:                                                 
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
./script.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: From the facts that you wrote _my script **looks like** this_ and that the posted script does not exhibit the `syntax error` you mentioned, I concluded that you didn't post the actual script with the error. If the shown script is the real script and you get the error with this very script, I apologize.

Comment: @Armali No worries. The other script was near identical. With one exception: instead of "for file in /path/*.star; do"  it used "foreach file (*.star)" But when I ran it I got an error not recognizing the command "foreach", which I think is a c-shell thing. So hence I tried to change it to something that works in bash, but then get a syntax error. Hence why I think the problem is that line. Somehow is not reading each file as it supposed to.

Comment: Ah, I should have recognized this earlier: Your file has CR/LF line endings, that's the reason of the syntax error. How did you create it? How do you edit it?

Comment: Ah solved the issue! thanks @Armali! I installed dos2unix and converted the file. I did not know what CR/LF line endings were but that makes sense reading about it.